# Asus ROG G752VM no battery detected

Tags: windows-10, battery, asus-laptop, battery-life

My ASUS laptop today didn't turn on when I pressed the button to switch it on.

Adding the power supply, the laptop turned on, and noticed the battery icon shows 'no battery detected".

I have tried updating the drivers on battery in device manager, I have ran troubleshooting on battery, which showed no errors, and finally I turned off the laptop and tried holding the power button for 60 seconds.

If you take the power cord out with the laptop on, it will immediately turn off.

There has never been any issues before and wondered if this is a battery issue or something else. The battery is enclosed and is not something you can pull out.

Is there anything I can do to determine what the problem is and what to do to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The battery has failed. When that happens, the device driver cannot find it.

As the battery is not user replaceable, you need to take the machine to a local repair shop and have them assess / replace the battery.

Comment: Hi I have just looked at how easy it is to replace the battery and it seems like a lot disassembly just to do the job. At laptop that is only four years old and it's gone. Is there any harm simply continuing using the charger indefinitely?

Comment: You need to replace the battery. Charger only has often caused many issues (intermittent or accidental disconnection, no BIOS updates and so on). You should have a local shop replace the battery.  (It is a lot work to replace my battery - same built in issue)